# Mysql weighting unique fields by external values

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm currently searching for a possibility to order a mysql result by weights that are not part of the result set or the database itself. The only link between the database and the weights is based on one unique column for what the weights exist.

To be more precise i've got the MySql table

```
+-------------------+
|Food               |
+-------------------+
|id:int(unique)     |
|name:string        |
+-------------------+
```

and one **external** source of weights for the food ids. For example a user weightens food 1 with 100, food 2 with 200 and food 3 with 50. What i want is to order the result by the weights given by the user.

Do you have any ideas how i can apply these external info into the result?

---

Edit: I'm not searching for a solution which orders the query result afterwards! I want the result to be ordered by the mysql server.

Comment: what you mean by external source ?

Comment: I am currently coding this in php so the external source is a php array (previously filled by a REST request) in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go :

```
SELECT
CASE id 
when 1 then 300
when 2 then 100
when 3 then 200
END as weight 
from tab 
order by weight;
```

What you do here is replace your existing row values with your custom values, and then sort it with those values.

Comment: That's exactly what i've been looking for. Thank you very much!

Comment: Well if it is correct, you can accept it as the correct answer! :)

Comment: Do you know whether mysql maps the weight to id and whether indexes can also be used with this mapping?

Comment: I don't think indexes will come into picture here, as this is a temporary mapping and indexes are stored in memory by databases. But then I am not sure of it completely, will try to find an answer and will post if I get something.

Comment: @Subodh hey, sorry to bother you, but I'm having the same problem and was wondering if there's any other solution to that? I use ORM and I don't really think building CASE of let's say 1500~ conditions (I must sort whole table and only return 12~ results per page) is a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

If your external source is `php` `array`. then you should use php `array` `sorting` functions instead of sorting in mysql query.

Fetch reuired data from mysql table and make a php array of that. Now make a array of external source and combine both array and use `array` sorting.

listed her  PHP array sorting functions. You can use as required.

http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php

Comment: This looks good for a small amount of data. In my case the db table consists of more than a million entries. Accordingly the fetching of the complete dataset int the first step just for ordering and filtering the set to 50 entries should be more expensive then using the mysql functionality instead. Nevertheless thank you for your answer!